# ERROR 1066: Unable to open iteratorfor alias

Tags: apache-pig

Command run (trying to get Maximum run scored)

```
Run_M = foreach Run_Group_All generate (Match.Player, Match.Run) , MAX(Match.Run);
```

As per log Group command is failing , can anybody help where is problem?

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2103: Problem doing work on Longs
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:556)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2103: Problem doing work on Longs
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicLongMathBase.doTupleWork(AlgebraicLongMathBase.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicLongMathBase.exec(AlgebraicLongMathBase.java:93)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicLongMathBase.exec(AlgebraicLongMathBase.java:37)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:326)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextLong(POUserFunc.java:410)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:351)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:400)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:317)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:474)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:442)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:422)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:346)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicLongMathBase.doTupleWork(AlgebraicLongMathBase.java:77)
    ... 20 more
2017-09-03 07:48:03,212 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2017-09-03 07:48:03,212 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_local1294624349_0011 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2017-09-03 07:48:03,212 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2017-09-03 07:48:03,213 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-09-03 07:48:03,214 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-09-03 07:48:03,214 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2017-09-03 07:48:03,215 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.8.1   0.15.0  goldi   2017-09-03 07:48:01 2017-09-03 07:48:03 GROUP_BY

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local1294624349_0011    Cric,Match,Run_Group_All,Run_M  GROUP_BY    Message: Job failed!    file:/tmp/temp-1949037811/tmp1601097545,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/goldi/Batting.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp-1949037811/tmp1601097545"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local1294624349_0011


2017-09-03 07:48:03,217 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2017-09-03 07:48:03,218 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias Run_M
Details at logfile: /home/goldi/pig_1504365116860.log
```

Comment: post your entire script

Answer (score 0):

Replace '(Match.Player, Match.Run)' with 'group'.

```
Run_M = foreach Run_Group_All generate FLATTEN(group) as (player,run) , MAX(Match.Run);
```

Comment: grunt> Run_M = foreach Run_Group_All generate group as (Player,Run) , MAX(Match.Run);
2017-09-03 10:39:34,889 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1031: Incompatable schema: left is "Player:NULL,Run:NULL", right is "group:chararray"

Comment: Please post your entire script and sample data.